# Debugging Boost.Test in Eclipse: debugger won't stop at break points

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, boost-test

When I set a breakpoint in eclipse to debug a boost unit test, it doesn't stop. I have it compiled with debugging symbols but it just goes right past the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you need to add an argument to the test executable.

Under the Debug Configurations for the test you need to set a program argument under the Arguments tab.

```
--catch_system_errors=no
```

Otherwise the executable ignores the information about the breakpoint.